# Shiny Parallel Coordinates with Brushing and Linking

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, parallel-coordinates

I'm creating a flexdashboard / Shiny app in R using Rstudio and am trying to create a dashboard with two components: a parallel coordinates graph on top and a table below the graph.

I'm trying to use Brushing and Linking to select specific axis in the parallel coordinate graph to affect and filter data in the table.

Below is my code (adapted from https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-ggplot2-brushing/):

````
    ---
    title: "ggplot2 Brushing"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        social: menu
        source_code: embed
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r global, include=FALSE}
    # load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
    library(datasets)
    mtcars2 <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "wt")]
    ```


    ```{r}
    # Reactive that returns the whole dataset if there is no brush
    selectedData <- reactive({
      data <- brushedPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_brush)
      if (nrow(data) == 0)
        data <- mtcars2
      data
    })
    ```

    Column {data-width=650}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ### Miles Per Gallon vs. Weight {data-width=600}

    ```{r}
    library(ggplot2)
    library(GGally)
    plotOutput("plot1", brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush"))
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      ggparcoord(mtcars2) + geom_line()
    })
    ```

    ### Car Details {data-width=400}

    ```{r}
    renderTable({
      selectedData()
    }, rownames = TRUE)
    ```
````

As you can see, brushing and linking are not working. What am I missing here? I've read a few questions about the topic and particularly around XY variables and only working for scatterplots, etc. But certainly there is a way around this and I can't seem to find a solution. Does anybody have an idea on how to make brushing and linking work with parallel coordinates in Shiny?

Comment: it does not seem that parallel coordinates plot of `ggplot2`is supported with brush..You could have a look at `plotly` package instead

Comment: Thanks @Malvina_a. I had a look at Plotly but wanted to achieve this in R / Shiny. Also, see further on: https://community.plot.ly/t/is-brushing-and-linking-available-for-the-python-api-in-plotly/2835

Comment: there is brushing and linking available in plotly, have a look at this link: https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/

Comment: Thanks again @Malvina_a. I''give it a try but it looks like all the input graphs are XY coordinates (scatterplots) which leads me to think it depends on having a clearly defined xvar.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find solution to Your problem but actually it is not possible at this moment to retrieve the data using `brush` from any parallel coordinates plot (neither `plotly` or `ggplot2`). You can easily use the brush in `plotly`, but You will not be able to get the data out of it (in Your case it is `selectedData()`). Maybe You should try another plot type.